# UIImage resizing. OK on simulator, not on device

Tags: ios4, uiimage, ios-simulator, device

In an iPhone app, I wrote some code to resize an image taken from the photo album, in order to use it as background for the app.
The code is strongly inspired from what I could find looking on the net. Namely here:
http://forrst.com/posts/UIImage_simple_resize_and_crop_image-sUG#comment-land
It works fine on the simulator. But it looks like no resizing at all is happening on the device. Why is that? Any idea?

Thank you for any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hi Michel.
>
> i dont know more about your code but i am using this code you can try
>   this you will find your solution.
>
> here you need to pass image and the required  width and height for
>   that image in this function and you will get another image with that
>   new size.

```
 -(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image3 width:(int)width height:(int)height {

        CGImageRef imageRef = [image3 CGImage];
        CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

        //if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

        CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
        CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

        CGContextRelease(bitmap);
        CGImageRelease(ref);

        return result;  

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Kartik; I tried your code. Here is the result. It works on the device. It seems unstable on the simulator. More precisely, if I use the feature in Portrait mode, then it will not work in landscape mode, or vice versa. I haven't yet digged deeply into this to know exactly what is happening. I like the shortness of your solution. But I need to clarify the issue I mentioned, to finalize my code.

Comment: My first comment might not be exact, rather than the orientation it seems that the code is working perfectly on some pictures and not on some others. I do not know why yet.

Comment: What I meant is, when I use your code; it is working fine with this picture:
http://www.public-domain-photos.com/animals/scared-looking-cat-free-stock-photo-3.htm
but not with these ones:
http://www.pdclipart.org/displayimage.php?album=19&pos=27
http://www.pdclipart.org/displayimage.php?album=21&pos=8
I tried both on the simulator and the device; I get the same result.

But, but when I add your code at the end of the one I was using before it works, on both simulator and device.

Thanks again for your tip.